# Открытие модального окна при нажатии клавиши

Tags: java, javafx

Имеется класс (контроллер), в котором при нажатии кнопки открывается модальное окно. Но компилятор ругается на `static`.
первое окно, в котором происходит запуск модального окна

```
public void sa (ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        run.setOnAction(event1 -> Lab2.display());
    }
   catch (IOException e){

   }
}
```

модальное окно

```
public class Lab2 {
 public static void display() throws IOException  {

    Stage dialog = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("lb2.fxml"));
    dialog.setWidth(2000);
    dialog.setHeight(2000);
    dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    Label l =  new Label("One");
    dialog.show();

 }
}
```

Comment: А как ругается то?

Comment: он ругается на getClass() из-за того, что метод static. А если я убираю static, то первый контроллер говорит, что зря я его убрал

Answer (score 1):

Замените `getClass()` на `Lab2.class`.